# Spring Hibernate validation is happening multiple times

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation, spring-mvc

I am using spring 4 and hibernate 4 to develop my application. I created my own custom validator to do unique check from the DB. It is working fine but. control is coming two times there:

1. normal spring validation (this is what i impelemented and working fine)
2. when I am saving data into DB (This one I think hibernate is handling on it own and my dao layer call is coming null thats ahy throwing exception)

I am using hibernate validator 5.1 jar.

How can I solve my problem? I have to either stop 2nd point or make it successful.

Right now I am not giving you any code detail. Let me which configuration you want me to put here. I will provide that.

HIbernate configuration

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>             
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.app"></property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the Hibernate auto validation mode via set the `validation-mode` attribute `(javax.persistence.validation.mode)` in your `persistence.xml` file to `none`, as described [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/additionalmodules.html#d0e4090) in the Hibernate documentations

```
<validation-mode>NONE</validation-mode>
```

> auto (default): enable integration between Bean Validation and Hibernate (callback and ddl generation) only if Bean Validation is present in the classpath.
>
> none: disable all integration between Bean Validation and Hibernate

Comment: I think it will disable all the bean validation...spring validation also..am i right?

Comment: It will disable the automatic one called by Hibernate as the documentation says

Comment: I dont have any persistent.xml..I am using annotation...how can i do it using anotation

Comment: I have only one tag configuration for hibernate..that i have added above